# How to call api from another domain angular typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I want to call  web service from another domain using angular2 typescript.
i am using following code to call api

```
    var req_dict = { 
               method: RequestMethod.Get,
               url: 'http//127.0.0.1:5000/users/',
               headers: this.head
              }
    var options = new RequestOptions(req_dict);
    var req = new Request(options);
    this.http.request(req).subscribe({});
```

I hosted my application  in http//127.0.0.1:8000. I want to use api from port 5000. when i inspected console , request is going to 
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/http//127.0.0.1:5000/users/**
i want to call just **http//127.0.0.1:5000/users/**. how can call api by absolute url in angular2 ?

Comment: check your url  `url: 'http//127.0.0.1:5000/users/' ` it should be  `url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/'`

Comment: Even if you use http it should be `url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/'`

Comment: oh.. yeah.. thanks. worked

Answer (score 4):

In fact, it's not an issue of TypeScript or Angular2 but a CORS issue. These blog posts could help you to understand in details how this works:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

To be short, in the case of cross domain request, the browser automatically adds an `Origin` header in the request. There are two cases:

- **Simple requests**. This use case applies if we use HTTP GET, HEAD and POST methods. In the case of POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.
- **Preflighted requests**. When the "simple requests" use case doesn't apply, a first request (with the HTTP OPTIONS method) is made to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

So in fact most of work must be done on the server side to return the CORS headers. The main one is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` one.

```
200 OK HTTP/1.1
(...)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

To debug such issues, you can use developer tools within browsers (Network tab).

Regarding Angular2, simply use the `Http` object like any other requests (same domain for example):

```
return this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/')
           .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Yes, even if the url was correctly formatted, CORS comes into to play as the ports are different.  On a side note (IMHO), using `subscribe` on the `http.get` could potentially block the component rendering.  Maybe a better approach is to use the `async` pipe on the component.